# how can i get html in ajax instead of value?

Tags: jquery

Here I have code of ajax i am getting value instead of html

```
jQuery('#phone').on('change', function(){

jQuery.ajax({
url: "get_phone.php",
type: "GET",
data: {
phone: jQuery('#phone').val()
},
success: function(response) {
//var phone = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                        jQuery("#dropdown").val(response); 
}
});
});
```

Comment: jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#phone').on('change', function(){

jQuery.ajax({
url: "get_phone.php",
type: "GET",
data: {
phone: jQuery('#phone').val()
},
success: function(response) {
//var phone = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                        jQuery("#dropdown").html(response); 
}
});
});
```

//use .html instead .val

Answer (score 3):

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use $().html() instead of $().val();

you may specify the  dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

```
jQuery('#phone').on('change', function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "get_phone.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html", // as you desired
    data: {
        phone: jQuery('#phone').val()
    },
    success: function(response) {
        //var phone = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        jQuery("#dropdown").val(response); 
    }
    });
});
```